# Get sharepoint siteurl using weburl with MS Graph

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, onenote, onenote-api

I have onenote notebooks hosted at sharedpoint. I have a weburl to access that notebook. How I can retrieve siteId and siteCollectionId using webUrl with MS Graph API.

Sample webUrl is -

> https://companyall-my.sharepoint.com/personal/ash_desh_company_com/Documents/Notebooks/Notebook1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you encode the `webUrl` using [this process](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/shares_get#encoding-sharing-urls) and then make a request to the following you should be able to access the ids:

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/shares/{encodedurl}/site?select=sharepointIds

As an example, for the example URL you provided it would look like:

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/shares/u!aHR0cHM6Ly9jb21wYW55YWxsLW15LnNoYXJlcG9pbnQuY29tL3BlcnNvbmFsL2FzaF9kZXNoX2NvbXBhbnlfY29tL0RvY3VtZW50cy9Ob3RlYm9va3MvTm90ZWJvb2sx/site?select=sharepointIds

Note that the ids are returned using the older nomenclature, so siteId = siteCollectionId and webId = siteId

Comment: Thanks Brad, I'll check the solution and will let you know if it worked for me or not